# What does the verb "run" mean in this book about algorithms?

Tags: word-usage

Below is a phrase from chapter 1 of the book: [Introduction to Algorithms](https://www.amazon.in/INTRODUCTION-ALGORITHMS-FOURTH-Charles-Leiserson/dp/026204630X).

I do not understand the usage of the verb `run` in the last line of:

> For many years, we could count on processor clock speeds increasing at a steady
> rate. Physical limitations present a fundamental roadblock to ever-increasing clock
> speeds, however: because power density increases superlinearly with clock speed,
> chips run the risk of melting once their clock speeds become high enough.

Comment: What research have you done? For example, have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: Identification of an idiom is difficult and they aren't easily pulled from a dictionary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"run the risk" is an idiom. It means to do something risky. See [Cambridge *run the risk of doing something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-the-risk-of-doing)

It means that if you increase clock speeds, it is risky, because the chip might melt.